# Change TTPhotoViewController UI

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am using TTPhotoViewController for show image in Photo viewer.

i tried to change the UI and remove the "See All" button in the navigationbar but i didn't succeed to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I have tried to do this myself, overriding the view methods and setting the nav bar doesn't help.

If you remove out the code responsible in TTPhotoViewController.m it will work however:

> ```
> if (_photoSource.numberOfPhotos > 1) {
>   self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem =
>   [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:TTLocalizedString(@"See All",
>                                                             @"See all photo thumbnails")
>                                     style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
>                                    target:self
>                                    action:@selector(showThumbnails)]
>    autorelease];
>
> } else {
>   self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil;
> }
> ```